# Android Studio Unable to generate signed APK

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created an app. When I execute it in debug mode it works fine. But when I want to generate the signed APK I am getting the following errors

> Android resource linking failed
> F:\Android Studio Projects\NMT\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:28: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_nmt (aka com.example.thumbsol.accuratesurvey:mipmap/ic_launcher_nmt) not found.
> F:\Android Studio Projects\NMT\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:28: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round_new_nmt_round (aka com.example.thumbsol.accuratesurvey:mipmap/ic_launcher_round_new_nmt_round) not found.
> error: failed processing manifest.

Here is the link to my [launcher icon](https://ibb.co/ZNK1W3Q)

Below is the manifest

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_nmt"
    android:label="@string/app_banner"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round_new_nmt_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:label">
.
.
.
 </application>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: can you add a full image of the res folder structure, maybe you put the res folder inside debug folder that's the way getting an error

Answer (score 0):

Check this in your project

the folder structure looks like this

```
[Project Root]
  -[Module]
    -src
      -main
        -res
          -mipmap-*
            -ic_launcher.png
```

in the android studio looks like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz1Ud.jpg

Answer (score 0):

change the project view to "Project" and under res, folder check if the mipmap folders are there. maybe when you are creating a logo, you are choosing debug not main. make sure.

[image]